# "compress this drive to save disk space" registry value

Tags: sql-server, windows

I need to include sql server as a prerequisite for my application. 
But the sql server does not install fine on windows machine where the volume is compressed.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231347

Does anyone know what is registry value for a disc drive for "compress this drive to save disk space" if it is turned on/off or is there a way to identify if the compression is on for a disc volume.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think there's a registry value for this? AFAIK, it's an attribute on the volume itself on disk.

Comment: I found out online that there is a way from registry to disable the compression. So i thought it might be registry. I have updated the question. Just wanted to know if there is a way i can identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get compression data from registry.

Pretty sure you have to use WMI for this.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Compressed Data type: boolean Access type: Read-only If true, the
>   volume exists as one compressed entity, such as a DoubleSpace volume.
>   If file-based compression is supported, such as the NTFS file system,
>   this property is false.